# How to split NSArray into multiple different arrays based on an NSArray of indexes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an `NSArray` that needs to be split into multiple arrays. I need to split them based on indexes I have in a separate `NSArray` array. So for example, my index array `*arrayIndexes` looks like this:

```
6
8
20
45
```

These are the indexes I need to split my single array on. Is there a simple/quick way to do this with Objective-C?

Comment: Can you describe the output?  is it 0..5, 6..7, 8..19?

Comment: No, the output is what you see above. Each of those numbers is the index I need to split my other array on. So I need arrays from index 0 to 5, 6 to 7, 8 to 19, 20 to 44, and 45 to the end.

Comment: Two down votes without a single comment on WHY I am getting a down vote?

Comment: You can use `subarrayWithRange:` to do what you want? Apparently, there is no "all built in solution".

Comment: Didn't downvote, and agree that most downvotes ought to be explained.  I'd speculate that these are the result of the OP not containing an attempted solution.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but your question wasn't clear enough, giving the wanting output could have been useful (see comment on @danh), then maybe a sample test code from you, asking on how you could optimize it, make it clearer, or make it work (in cas you have issue with it) may have avoid you some down vote, but it's just speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [subarrayWithRange:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1415157-subarraywithrange?language=objc) go get it done, below is an example

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Temp1",@"Temp2",@"Temp3",@"Temp4",@"Temp5",@"Temp6",@"Temp7",@"Temp8",@"Temp9",@"Temp10",@"Temp11",@"Temp12",@"Temp13",@"Temp14",@"Temp15",@"Temp16",@"Temp17",@"Temp18", nil];
NSArray *arrIndex = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"4",@"10",@"12",@"14", nil];
NSMutableArray *arrTemp = [NSMutableArray new];
for  (int i=0;i<arrIndex.count;i++) {
    if (arrIndex.count == i+1) {
        [arrTemp addObject:[arr subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([arrIndex[i-1] intValue], arr.count - [arrIndex[i-1] intValue])]];
    } else if (i==0) {
        [arrTemp addObject:[arr subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [arrIndex[i] intValue])]];
    }else {
        [arrTemp addObject:[arr subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([arrIndex[i-1] intValue],[arrIndex[i] intValue]-[arrIndex[i-1] intValue])]];
    }
}
for (NSArray *arr in arrTemp) {
    NSLog(@"Arra - %@",arr);
}
```

Comment: FYI - do not create `NSRange` using that syntax. Use the `NSMakeRange` function.

Answer (score 1):

The `subarrayWithRange:` method is the way to go.  Here's a working test that demonstrates.  Notice that it reuses the same NSRange structure on each iteration.

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13];
NSArray *arrayIndexes = @[@5,@9,@11];
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSUInteger location=0;
NSRange range;

for (NSNumber *index in arrayIndexes) {
    range.location = location;
    range.length = [index intValue] - location;
    [results addObject:[myArray subarrayWithRange:range]];
    location = [index intValue];
}
NSLog(@"%@", results);
```